# Describe set of integers $x$ such that the $p$-adic norm of $(x-a)$ is smaller than $p^{-e}$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

How to describe set of integers $x$ such that the $p$-adic norm of $(x-a)$ is smaller than $p^{-e}$?

i.e. How can I use the language of congruence to describe the set of integers $x$ such  that $|x-a|p< p^{-e}$?

Comment: I think that you’ll get a much better feel for the situation if you translate $|a|_p\le p^{-m}$ into the mathematically equivalent statement $v_p(a)\ge m$. Here, $v_p(p)=1$ and $v_p(n)=0$ if $\gcd(p,n)=1$, to be extended to be multiplicative: $v_p(nn')=v_p(n)+v_p(n')$. This notation seems to me to lie midway between the norm notation and the congruence notation. **And** while you’re at it, it will help us all if you learn mathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given integer $a$ and prime number $p$, the $p$-adic norm of $x-a$ is smaller than $p^{-e}$ if and only if $v_p(x-a)>e$. That is to say, if and only if $x-a$ is divisible by a power of $p$ greater than $e$, i.e. $x-a=p^{e+1}b$ for some integer $b$. In this way we find that your set of integers is precisely the set
$$\{a+bp^{e+1}:\ b\in\Bbb{Z}\}.$$
In terms of congruences this can be written as
$$\{x\in\Bbb{Z}:\ x\equiv a\pmod{p^{e+1}}\}.$$